# how to use Vuex in Laravel + Vue 3 project

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuex

working with Laravel + Vue 3 project. I need work with Vuex in the project. I have configure My Vuex in `store.js` file as following

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

const store = createStore({
      /* state, actions, mutations */
    state : {
        counter : 1000
    }
    
    });
      
const app = createApp();
app.use(store);
app.mount("#app");
```

and My `app.js` file as following

```
import ViewUIPlus from 'view-ui-plus'
import 'view-ui-plus/dist/styles/viewuiplus.css'
import 'view-ui-plus/dist/styles/viewuiplus.css'
import common from './common'
import store from './store' //import store.js

createApp({
    components: {
        mainapp,
        
    }
    
}).use(router).use(ViewUIPlus).mixin(common).mount('#app');
```

now I am unable to how to import store.js in to the app.js file. could you give some solution here

Comment: You haven’t exported anything from that file so you can’t import anything. Export what you need.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I need add store.js file with app.js like `.use(router).use(ViewUIPlus).mixin(common)` that is my need

Comment: You should be aware that Vuex has been deprecated in favor of Pinia. https://pinia.vuejs.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important note: Vue core team members (including Vuex authors) *highly recommend* using Pinia instead of Vuex for new projects, on the [very first page](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) of Vuex docs.

---

You're currently creating two separate apps:

- one in `store.js` (which has the store but nothing else)
- one in `app.js` (which has everything but the store).

You probably want to add the store to the app in `app.js`, not to a separate app. You should export the store from `store.js` and import + use it into `app.js`:

**store.js**

```js
export const store = createStore({
  //...
})
```

**app.js**:

```js
import { store } from './store'

const app = createApp({
  //...
})
  .use(router)
  .use(store)
  .use(ViewUIPlus)
  .mixin(common)
  .mount('#app')
```